# How to create criteria in groovy/grails for nested object?

Tags: hibernate, grails, criteria

I need help on creating hibernate criteria for nested object. For example :

```
class office{
    Integer id;
    OfficeDetails cmdData ;
}

class OfficeDetails {
    Integer id;
    Region region;

}

class Region {
    Integer id;
    Integer regionNum;
}
```

Now, from the service class ( officeService) I am trying to pull up all of the offices that matches a certain region as :

```
List<Office> findAllByRegion( Integer regionNumber){
    def criteria =  {  eq ( 'cmdData.region.regionNum', regionNumber ) }
    def allOfficesInTheRegion =  Office.findAll(criteria)

    return allOfficesInTheRegion
}
```

Always getting exception :"org.hibernate.QueryException: could not resolve property:"
I need to find out right way to create criteria for this query.Can anyone help?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

See "querying associations" under the [criteria section of the user guide](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria):

```
def criteria = {
  cmdData {
    region {
      eq('regionNum', regionNumber)
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: For my and others benefit copying the working code:  def criteria = MyOffice.createCriteria();
           def results = criteria.list {
                                        cmtData {
                                            region {
                                                eq("regionNum", regionNumber)
                                            }
                                        }
                                    };

        return results;